# MySQL aggregation query

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to aggregate the people who visited a sports facility and how much it cost them.
I have run the following code successfully but need to aggregate the people.
How can I do that.

The tables used for the code is here
[Tables](https://easyupload.io/ln1x7i)

```
SELECT CONCAT( members.firstname, " ", members.surname ) AS fullname,
CASE WHEN slots >0
THEN (
bookings.slots * facilities.membercost + bookings.slots * facilities.guestcost
)
ELSE NULL
END AS "cost"
FROM `Bookings` AS bookings
LEFT JOIN `Members` AS members ON bookings.memid = members.memid
LEFT JOIN Facilities AS facilities ON bookings.facid = facilities.facid
WHERE bookings.starttime LIKE '2012-09-14%'
AND (
bookings.slots * facilities.membercost + bookings.slots * facilities.guestcost
) >30
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

[OutputScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uncDA.jpg)

Comment: 1. ```bookings.starttime LIKE '2012-09-14%'``` => ```bookings.starttime >= '2012-09-14'``` 2. You can use INNER JOIN as bookings records without members/facilities would be filtered out by WHERE anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I got throught with this....
Here is my solution:

```
SELECT CONCAT (members.firstname," ",members.surname) AS fullname,
    SUM(bookings.slots*facilities.membercost + bookings.slots*facilities.guestcost) AS cost

    FROM `Bookings` AS bookings
            LEFT JOIN `Members` AS members 
            ON bookings.memid = members.memid
            LEFT JOIN Facilities as facilities
            ON bookings.facid =facilities.facid
    WHERE bookings.starttime LIKE '2012-09-14%' AND (bookings.slots*facilities.membercost + bookings.slots*facilities.guestcost) >30


GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```